# What's the difference between gasPrice and effectiveGasPrice?

Tags: transactions

I have found that there are two columns in rpc calls.

1. For getting transaction `eth_getTransactionByHash`

```
gasPrice: QUANTITY - gas price provided by the sender in Wei.
```

2. For getting transaction receipt `eth_getTransactionReceipt`

```
effectiveGasPrice : QUANTITY - The sum of the base fee and tip paid per unit of gas.
```

What's the difference? I found that for some transactions both values are the same, but for some they are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General explanation:

1.`gasPrice`: Used prior to **EIP-1559**, it was the fee that users set for each unit of gas to execute their transactions. You had to guess the right fee to have the transaction processed quickly, leading to less predictability and potential bidding wars.

2.`effectiveGasPrice`: Introduced after **EIP-1559**, it represents the actual fee per unit of gas, which includes a `base_fee` (automatically adjusted by the network) and an optional `miner_tip` to prioritize transactions.

So, while both `gasPrice` and `effectiveGasPrice` represent fees paid for transactions, they are used in different contexts (before and after **EIP-1559**)